# Smarty PHP модальное окно

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, form, smarty

Здравствуйте. Есть данный код на smarty, который добавляет на страницу формы для отправки информации на почту.

```html
{include file="db:header.tpl" h1=$anketa.name}
<!--includeForm-->
{if $anketa}

{if !$anketa.posted}

<form method="post">

{if $anketa && $anketa.dictionaries}
{if isset($smarty.get.form)}
 <h2 class="form-title">{$h1|default:$page.name|strip_tags}</h2>
{/if}

{foreach from=$anketa.dictionaries item=e name=foo}

{if isset($smarty.get.form)}

 {assign var=count value=$smarty.foreach.foo.iteration}


 {if $smarty.foreach.foo.first}<div class="cell">{/if}

 {if $e.type_code=="TEXT"} {* ======================= *}
  <div class="row">
   {if $e.name}<div class="row-title">{$e.name}:{if $e.required==1}<span style="color:red">*</span>{/if}</div>{/if}
   <input{if $e.error!=""} required="required"{/if} type="text" size="{$e.size}" maxlength="{$e.maxlength}" value="{$e.value|htmlspecialchars}" name="d[{$e.dictionary_position}]" id="d[{$e.dictionary_position}]" required>
  </div>
 
 {elseif $e.type_code=="TEXTAREA"} {* ======================= *}
  <div class="row">
   {if $e.name}<div class="row-title">{$e.name}:{if $e.required==1}<span style="color:red">*</span>{/if}</div>{/if}
   <textarea{if $e.error!=""} required="required"{/if} name="d[{$e.dictionary_position}]" id="d[{$e.dictionary_position}]" required>{$e.value|htmlspecialchars}</textarea>
  </div>
 {/if}

 {if !($count % 2)}</div><div class="cell">{/if}
 {if $smarty.foreach.foo.last}</div>{/if}

{else}


{if $e.type_code=="TEXT" || $e.type_code=="EMAIL"} {* ======================= *}

{if $e.error!=""}<span style="color:red">{$e.error}</span><br />{/if}
{if $e.name}<b>{$e.name}:</b>{if $e.required==1}<span style="color:red">*</span>{/if}<br />{/if}
<input type="text" size="{$e.size}" maxlength="{$e.maxlength}" value="{$e.value|htmlspecialchars}" name="d[{$e.dictionary_position}]" id="d[{$e.dictionary_position}]" />
{if $e.note!=""}<br /><small>{$e.note}</small>{/if}


{elseif $e.type_code=="TEXTAREA"} {* ======================= *}

{if $e.error!=""}<span style="color:red">{$e.error}</span><br />{/if}
{if $e.name!=""}<b>{$e.name}:</b>{if $e.required==1}<span style="color:red">*</span>{/if}<br />{/if}
<textarea cols="{$e.cols}" rows="{$e.rows}" name="d[{$e.dictionary_position}]" id="d[{$e.dictionary_position}]">{$e.value|htmlspecialchars}</textarea>
{if $e.note!=""}<br /><small>{$e.note}</small>{/if}

{elseif $e.type_code=="DIV"}  {* ======================= *}

<span style="font-weight:bold;">{$e.name}</span><hr />
{if $e.note!=""}<small>{$e.note}</small>{/if}

{elseif $e.type_code=="SELECT"}  {* ======================= *}

{if $e.error!=""}<span style="color:red">{$e.error}</span><br />{/if}
{if $e.name}<b>{$e.name}:</b>{if $e.required==1}<span style="color:red">*</span>{/if}<br />{/if}
<select name="d[{$e.dictionary_position}]" id="d[{$e.dictionary_position}]" >
{if $e.requered!=1}<option></option>{/if}
{foreach from=$e.options item=option}
<option value="{$option.name}" {if $option.selected==true}selected{/if} >{$option.name}</option>
{/foreach}




</select>
{if $e.note!=""}<br /><small>{$e.note}</small>{/if}

{elseif $e.type_code=="MULTI_SELECT"} {* ======================= *}

{if $e.error!=""}<span style="color:red">{$e.error}</span><br />{/if}
{if $e.name}<b>{$e.name}:</b>{if $e.required==1}<span style="color:red">*</span>{/if}<br />{/if}
<select multiple name="d[{$e.dictionary_position}][]" id="d[{$e.dictionary_position}][]">
{foreach from=$e.options item=option}
<option value="{$option.name}" {if $option.selected==true}selected{/if} >{$option.name}</option>
{/foreach}




</select>
{if $e.note!=""}<br /><small>{$e.note}</small>{/if}

{elseif $e.type_code=="MULTI_CHECKBOX"} {* ======================= *}

{if $e.error!=""}<span style="color:red">{$e.error}</span><br />{/if}
{if $e.name}<b>{$e.name}:</b>{if $e.required==1}<span style="color:red">*</span>{/if}<br />{/if}
{foreach from=$e.options item=option}
<input type="checkbox" value="{$option.name}" {if $option.selected==true}checked{/if} id="d[{$e.dictionary_position}][]" name="d[{$e.dictionary_position}][]" />{$option.name}<br />
{/foreach}




{if $e.note!=""}<small>{$e.note}</small>{/if}

{elseif $e.type_code=="CHECKBOX"} {* ======================= *}

<input type="checkbox" value="{$e.name}" {if $e.value==$e.name}checked{/if} id="d[{$e.dictionary_position}]" name="d[{$e.dictionary_position}]" />{$e.name}
{if $e.error!=""}<br /><span style="color:red">{$e.error}</span>{/if}
{if $e.note!=""}<br /><small>{$e.note}</small>{/if}

{elseif $e.type_code=="RADIO_GROUP"} {* ======================= *}

{if $e.error!=""}<span style="color:red">{$e.error}</span><br />{/if}
{if $e.name}<b>{$e.name}:</b>{if $e.required==1}<span style="color:red">*</span>{/if}<br />{/if}
{foreach from=$e.options item=option}<input type="radio" name="d[{$e.dictionary_position}]" value="{$option.name}" {if $option.selected==true}checked{/if} />{$option.name}<br />{/foreach}




{if $e.note!=""}<small>{$e.note}</small>{/if}

{elseif $e.type_code=="HTML_BLOCK"}{$e.html}

{elseif $e.type_code=="UPLOAD"} {* ========================= *}
{if !$_upload_css_attached}
{assign var="_upload_css_attached" value="1"}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/shared/s3/swfupload/default.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/shared/s3/swfupload/swfupload.upload.pack.js"></script>
{/if}
<span class="anketa-flash-upload">
{if $e.error}
<span style="background: #FFEEEE; color:red; border: 1px solid red; padding:5px">{$e.error}</span>
{elseif $e.uploaded}
<div class="fieldset flash"><span class="legend">{$e.name}</span>
{foreach from=$e.uploaded item=upload}
<div class="progressWrapper"><div class="progressContainer blue"><div class="progressName">{$upload.filename}</div><div class="progressBarStatus">{#UPLOADED#}...</div><div class="progressBarComplete"></div></div></div>
{/foreach}
<input type="hidden" name="d[{$e.dictionary_position}]" value="{$e.uploaded_str|escape}" />
</div>
{else}
<script type="text/javascript">
var JS_FORM_REQUIRED_FIELD = '{#BOARD_FILL_REQUIRED_FIELDS#}';
newSWFU({$e.dictionary_position}, {if $e.required==1}true{else}false{/if},  {$e.count}, "{$e.upload_url}", "{$e.upload_field}", "{$e.maxsize} MB",  "{$e.filetypes.1}", "{$e.filetypes.0}", "{$e.buttontitle}");
</script>
<b>{$e.name}</b>
<div class="fieldset flash" id="fsUploadProgress{$e.dictionary_position}"></div>
<span class="buttonUpload" id="spanButtonPlaceHolder{$e.dictionary_position}"></span>
{if $e.required==1}<SPAN style="color:red">*</SPAN>{/if}
{if $e.count}<span class="no-more">{#NO_MORE#}: {$e.count}</span>{/if}
<input type="hidden" name="d[{$e.dictionary_position}]" id="hidUploadField{$e.dictionary_position}" value="" />
{if $e.note!=""}<br /><small>{$e.note}</small>{/if}
</span>
{/if}
{* ==DON`T_REMOVE_END_OF_CONTROL_SWITCH== *}
{* ======================= *}



{elseif $e.type_code=="CALENDAR"} {* ========================= *}
<span>
{if $e.error!=""}<span style="color:red">{$e.error}</span><br />{/if}
{if $e.name}<b>{$e.name}:</b>{if $e.required==1}<span style="color:red">*</span>{/if}<br />{/if}
<input type="text" name="d[{$e.dictionary_position}]" id="d[{$e.dictionary_position}]" value="{$e.value|escape}" readonly="true" class="init-calendar" />
</span>
{if $e.note!=""}<small><br />{$e.note}</small>{/if}

{elseif $e.type_code=="CALENDAR_INTERVAL"} {* ========================= *}
{if $e.error!=""}<span style="color:red">{$e.error}</span><br />{/if}
{if $e.name}<b>{$e.name}:</b>{if $e.required==1}<span style="color:red">*</span>{/if}<br />{/if}
{$e.label_from|default:#ANKETA_CALENDAR_INVERVAL_FROM#}
<span><input type="text" readonly="true" id="d[{$e.dictionary_position}][0]" value="{$e.value|regex_replace:"/^(d+.d+.d+)[^~]+/":"1"}" /></span>
&nbsp;{$e.label_to|default:#ANKETA_CALENDAR_INVERVAL_TO#}
<span><input type="text" readonly="true" id="d[{$e.dictionary_position}][1]" value="{$e.value|regex_replace:"/[^~]+?(d+.d+.d+)$/":"1"}" /></span>
<input class="init-calendar-interval" type="hidden" value="{$e.value|escape}" name="d[{$e.dictionary_position}]" id="d[{$e.dictionary_position}]" />
{if $e.note!=""}<br /><small>{$e.note}</small>{/if}

 {* ======================= *}

{/if}
<br /><br />
{/if}
{/foreach}





 {* == captcha == *}
{* Don't remove nor CAPTCHA, nor captcha/captcha end markers!!! *}
{if $anketa.captcha}
{literal}
<style>img.captcha {
border:1px solid gray;
}</style>
{/literal}

<span style="color:red">*</span><b>{#FORM_ENTER_CAPTCHA_CODE#}:</b><br/>

{captcha name="_cn"}
<br/>{if $anketa.captcha_error}<span style="color:red">{#WRONG_CAPTCHA_ERROR#}</span>{/if}
<br/>
{/if}
{* == captcha_end == *}

{if !isset($smarty.get.form)}
<br clear="all" /><br />
{/if}

<input type="submit" value="{$anketa.submit_name}" /></form>

{/if}


{else}
{$anketa.success_note}
{/if}
{/if}


<script src="/shared/misc/calendar.gen.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<!--includeForm-->
{include file="db:bottom.tpl"}
```

Есть модальное окно, которое отображает эти элементы со страницы, примерно так оно формирует его

```html
<div class="cell">
    <div class="row">
   <div class="row-title">Имя:</div>   <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="100" value="" name="d[0]" id="d[0]" required="">
  </div>
    <div class="row">
   <div class="row-title">Телефон:<span style="color:red">*</span></div>   <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="100" value="" name="d[1]" id="d[1]" required="">
  </div>
 </div>
```

```html
<div class="cell"> 
    <div class="row">
   <div class="row-title">Ваш заказ:</div>   <textarea name="d[2]" id="d[2]" required=""></textarea>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Формы в модальном окне отображаются только TEXT и TEXTAREA, остальные поля типа select и т.д не показываются, вместо них пустой div, как мне добавить остальные поля подскажите пожалуйста.

```html
<div class="cell"></div>
```

Comment: дак проверьте что у вас для этих полей в `e.type_code` содержится. вообще переусложненный шаблон какой-то, написанный на старом смарти еще

Comment: Я так понимаю эти строки остветственны за вывод в модальное окно, а как добавить туда select ?
 {if $e.type_code=="TEXT"} {* ======================= *}
  <div class="row">
   {if $e.name}<div class="row-title">{$e.name}:{if $e.required==1}<span style="color:red">*</span>{/if}</div>{/if}
   <input{if $e.error!=""} required="required"{/if} type="text" size="{$e.size}" maxlength="{$e.maxlength}" value="{$e.value|htmlspecialchars}" name="d[{$e.dictionary_position}]" id="d[{$e.dictionary_position}]" required>
  </div>

Comment: Что то вроде {elseif $e.type_code=="SELECT"} {* ======================= *} ????

Comment: у вас в шаблон передается массив `$anketa.dictionaries` вот там и смотрите что есть, и что туда добавить. Добавлять очевидно надо не в шаблоне, а там где у вас пхп код